# Artificial Intelligent patterns in an RTS environment

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, libgdx, artificial-intelligence

this appears to be a popular topic, however my question is rather specific. If this has been addressed before, please feel free to point me to those articles.

I'm designing an AI for a game which will be an RTS (Real Time Strategy). The Player will be against the AI, acting as a General, commanding various soldiers in a live-time (not turn based) arena. Now, other AIs I've seen focus on each soldier having it's own AI. I'm looking for an AI for the general, who directs the soldiers towards various goals. eg Go there, Attack this, Get this, etc

In a turn-based game, it is easy enough to analyse the field, and then act on it, issuing orders. However, in this live-time environment, that is not the case. I've currently setup a delay, so every 3 seconds the AI re-analyses the situation, because I don't want it happening 60 times a second (60FPS). Would there be a better way to deal with this?

Another issue I have is that the AI may see a situation needs addressing, and issues "orders" to the troops to "go to location X". On the next cycle/iteration of AI (after 3 seconds), if the soldiers have not yet reached their goal, what would be the best approach to keeping track of orders and seeing their completion status? eg: "AI: 20 Soldiers need to be moved from position X to position Z. Move now, oh wait, I already did that last time, just wait for them".

The key points are:
- The frequency of "analysing" the field
- Keeping track of previous "orders"
- The AI is the General overseeing the soldiers, and not the soldiers themselves

Any thoughts?

Many thanks for any help or pointers you can offer.

J

Comment: "what would be the best approach to keeping track of orders and seeing their completion status?" Maybe a [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) ?

Comment: probably, yes. I think communication should go in both ways (soldier -> general and general -> soldier) and it should be completely asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks, have implemented a basic command pattern for the time being. It's a step in the right direction. Have to focus on how the AI will frequently assess the situation and act upon that

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

The AI should be completely independent of the frames per second, I think that a good approach would be an event-driven algorithm.

So the General invest a good amount of time at the beginning to calculate it's long term strategy and transforms it into atomic commands to the soldiers (tactics).

Now 3 things may happen:

- **A soldier finishes a command** (by successfully completing it).
- **A soldier sends feedback to the general** (event).
  The events may be either generic or specific for a given command. At this point the general updates it's state (knowledge of the game) and rethinks it's long term strategy. It does not have to cancel and give another command to the soldier immediately but it can do it at some point if the long term strategy requires so.
- **The general changes its long-term strategy by other factor** that is not feedback from a soldier (timings, dynamic changes on difficulty, game time, actions or score from other player...). The same applies than previous point. The general may consider cancelling / assigning new commands to soldiers.

Note that the general may think in a background thread and/or use spare CPU time between frame and frame.

Soldiers must be able to accomplish its atomic commands without involving the general at all. IE: They know where they are, they know where they have to go, so they just do the next step that better suits. IE2: They know the enemy is still alive so they keep shooting until it is dead and then report to the general (goal successfully completed). IE3: They keep shooting but their live reaches a critical value, so they immediately report to the general (and keep shooting until they are given further orders).

Comment: Thanks for your response. An event-driven system makes sense. However, we already have a gameloop (game.render() loop) in progress so it would need to somehow fit in with that. Also everything is on the one thread at the moment. Would event-driven still be possible with this setup?

Comment: I'd say yes. The only problem is if there are too many events you will experience frame drops. I'd suggest to process events - IA in another thread with a timer after rendering the frame, so that your app appears more fluid. IA may look less responsive on slower devices though, if there are too many events to process. So in that case you will probably need a old-event drop policy or something like that